# getting German babel shortcuts to work with biblatex without autolang=langname

Tags: biblatex, babel, shorthands

I want to use babel language shortcuts in bibtex entries. This seems to be imposible unless `autolang=langname` is used. But if I use this setting, the item uses the German Hrsg instead of ed.

[image]

With the setting `autolang=hyphen` the language shortcuts seem to be ignored, even though they are seen outside of the bibliography in the document. Is there a way to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman,main=english]{babel}
\useshorthands*{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}


@incollection{Fanselow92,
Address = {Berlin, New York},
Author = {Gisbert Fanselow no langid},
Booktitle = {{Deutsche Syntax -- Ansichten und Aussichten}},
Editor = {Ludger Hoffmann},
Pages = {276--303},
Publisher = {de Gruyter},
Series = {Institut für deutsche Sprache, Jahrbuch 1991},
Title = {{{"`Ergative"' Verben und die Test/""Test Struktur des deutschen Mittelfelds}}},
Year = {1992}}

@incollection{Fanselow93,
Address = {Berlin, New York},
Author = {Gisbert Fanselow ngerman},
Booktitle = {{Deutsche Syntax -- Ansichten und Aussichten}},
Editor = {Ludger Hoffmann},
Pages = {276--303},
Publisher = {de Gruyter},
Series = {Institut für deutsche Sprache, Jahrbuch 1991},
Title = {{{"`Ergative"' Verben und die Test/""Test Struktur des deutschen Mittelfelds}}},
    langid = {ngerman},
Year = {1993}}



\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{bibentry}

\usepackage[
style=langsci-unified,
%autolang=langname,
    autolang=hyphen,
        backend=biber,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
Test"=Sequenz "`Ergative"' Verben Test/""Test

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: from your screenshot the quotes look ok. Why are you saying that they don't work?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The screenshot is a bit misleading for the question. It appears to show the situation with `autolang=langname,` (which is not desirable because it also translates the bibstrings). If I compile the MWE (which has `autolang=hyphen,`) I get a slightly different output, where `"` shorthands are not resolved in the `ngerman` entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite right that the `babel` shorthands only work with `autolang=langname`. In your example you have explicitly enabled German (specifically `ngerman`) shorthands also for `english`. The only languages relevant in your example are `english` and `ngerman`, so one might reasonably expect the shorthands to work in all situations.

Indeed the only case where shorthands don't work in your setup is `autolang=hyphen,`. That's because the `hyphenrules` environment that gets used with `autolang=hyphen,` explicitly disables language shorthands (the definition of `\hyphenrules` contains `\languageshorthands{none}%`). You can easily verify that with

```
\begin{hyphenrules}{ngerman}
Test"=Sequenz "`Ergative"' Verben Test/""Test
\end{hyphenrules}
```

With

```
\makeatletter
\def\hyphenrules#1{%
  \edef\bbl@tempf{#1}%
  \bbl@fixname\bbl@tempf
  \bbl@iflanguage\bbl@tempf{%
    \expandafter\bbl@patterns\expandafter{\bbl@tempf}%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname\bbl@tempf hyphenmins\endcsname\relax
      \set@hyphenmins\tw@\thr@@\relax
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\set@hyphenmins
      \csname\bbl@tempf hyphenmins\endcsname\relax
    \fi}}
\makeatother
```

you can stop `hyphenrules` from disabling language shorthands. We simply remove the `\languageshorthands{none}%` from the definition. This means you will be able to use the shorthands activated by the surrounding language.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman,main=english]{babel}
\useshorthands*{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}

\makeatletter
\def\hyphenrules#1{%
  \edef\bbl@tempf{#1}%
  \bbl@fixname\bbl@tempf
  \bbl@iflanguage\bbl@tempf{%
    \expandafter\bbl@patterns\expandafter{\bbl@tempf}%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname\bbl@tempf hyphenmins\endcsname\relax
      \set@hyphenmins\tw@\thr@@\relax
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\set@hyphenmins
      \csname\bbl@tempf hyphenmins\endcsname\relax
    \fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Fanselow92,
  Address   = {Berlin, New York},
  Author    = {Gisbert Fanselow no langid},
  Booktitle = {{Deutsche Syntax -- Ansichten und Aussichten}},
  Editor    = {Ludger Hoffmann},
  Pages     = {276--303},
  Publisher = {de Gruyter},
  Series    = {Institut für deutsche Sprache, Jahrbuch 1991},
  Title     = {{{"`Ergative"' Verben und die
               Test/""Test
               Struktur des deutschen Mittelfelds}}},
  Year      = {1992},
}
@incollection{Fanselow93,
  Address   = {Berlin, New York},
  Author    = {Gisbert Fanselow ngerman},
  Booktitle = {{Deutsche Syntax -- Ansichten und Aussichten}},
  Editor    = {Ludger Hoffmann},
  Pages     = {276--303},
  Publisher = {de Gruyter},
  Series    = {Institut für deutsche Sprache, Jahrbuch 1991},
  Title     = {{{"`Ergative"' Verben und die
               Test/""Test
               Struktur des deutschen Mittelfelds}}},
  langid    = {ngerman},
  Year      = {1993},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  style=langsci-unified,
  autolang=hyphen,
  backend=biber,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Test"=Sequenz "`Ergative"' Verben Test/""Test

\begin{hyphenrules}{ngerman}
Test"=Sequenz "`Ergative"' Verben Test/""Test
\end{hyphenrules}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: ngerman, Gisbert Fanselow. 1993. „Ergative“ Verben und die Test/Test Struktur des deutschen Mittelfelds. In Ludger Hoffmann (ed.), Deutsche Syntax – Ansichten und Aussichten (Institut für deutsche Sprache, Jahrbuch 1991), 276–303. Berlin, New York: de Gruyter.]

Comment: Shouldn't it be the default that the shorthands stay active? For me as the naive user this behavior is totally unexpected. I am coming from `german.sty` and with `german.sty` the shorthands just work independent of any environment. I do not see a reason for disabling them.

Comment: @StefanMüller It's debatable, I guess. But `hyphenrules` is documented as *just* setting hyphenation patterns, so it is not completely unreasonable to have it disable shorthands. You can always open an issue at the `babel` bugtracker (https://github.com/latex3/babel) and ask for a new environment. I highly doubt this established behaviour of `hyphenrules` can be changed without breaking backwards compatibility (but you can always ask).